# Junior title, senior responsibilities: how to make it count as career progression? Or should it be always avoided?

Tags: career-development

I have been offered a role where a foreign company would rely on me for building their presence in a new territory. Set up office, deal with regulators and stakeholders, bring in first few customers and deals, etc.

However, the head of the territory would be somebody flown over from the HQ. The role is more like a lower level manager/advisor who would be enabling this "HQ guy" to do his job; he would depend 100% from my knowledge and connections.

I would be doing some very important work, but without being given the role and title matching my responsibilities and contribution.
I am inclined to refuse the job, but maybe there is an opportunity I am missing.
For sure, I hate to think I would be doing somebody else's job.

**Is there a scenario where I can accept a more junior role with more senior responsibilities and still make it worth as career progression?**

Comment: "I would be doing some very important work, but without being given the role and title matching my responsibilities and contribution"   - what's the title /salary being offered to you?

Comment: middle manager level. Salary doesn't matter.

Comment: What's your current role? What are your career goals? It's hard to talk about career progression without more background info.

Comment: @Isaiah3015 the title would be "BD manager". They are looking for somebody with contacts not only in the market but also in government and various institutions, plus additional knowledge or contacts to navigate another country's regulations. This role is meant to enable them to do business, they will be dependent on this person. However, the shots will be called by the "head of" who will transfer from the main office. My career goal would be to be the "head of" directly, doing the same things and running operations.

Answer (score 5):

While Job title can *help* when looking at future roles the really important thing is what you **did** in the role. Make sure the responsibilities and duties are accurately described in your CV and that's what *really* counts. This sounds like a fantastic opportunity to build some very valuable experience and potentially springboard into "head of territory" type roles in the future if you were so inclined.

> For sure, I hate to think I would be doing somebody else's job.

Oh do grow up.. being a "do-er" or "enabler" for senior management is not "doing somebody else's job".

Comment: could you please add more to your last sentence.

Comment: From my experience the management level "does" relatively little during negotiations, it is generally one level down on both sides of the negotiations where  numbers are crunched, plans drawn and risks assesed, this is then communicated to the managers who "only" have to do the exact negotiations and communication with their counterpart. Both jobs depend on the other but culturally the negotiating side is the more senior one as they are usually the ones who sign the contracts.

Answer (score 2):

I totally understand your point, but i think the way you see the situation doesn't help you to see it from a good side.

Forget about junior, senior and all that. These words seems more relevant than they really are.

Think about this:

1. Is it a good oportunity to learn and do something new?
2. Would i do all that work for the money and benefits they offer to me?

But it is also important to think that, if you like the responsibilities offered, even if they don't pay you what you want, they will boost your resume, and you will be in a better position in the future to seek a job like that, in another company, and asking for more money and better benefits because you will have the experience. Or even you will be able to ask for a raise in that job because you have shown your work.
I'm not saying to accept any money, i'm talking about a situation when they don't match your expectations but the payment is fine to fit your needs anyway. It is obvious that you can't even consider this if you will also lose money.

**It's something very personal, and the final answer may change in different moments in your life**. **What's more important to you *now*?** If you don't have children to raise, and you want to build something for the future, **this seems like a great opportunity**.
A different choice would be if you need to earn big money and/or you have enough experience and knowledge to refuse a deal like this.

And final words, you won't be doing someone else's job, you will be doing what they pay you for. They are offering you something, no changing your role when you already have a position.